# How can I reload an Excel spreadsheet using a different encoding?

Tags: microsoft-excel, encoding, utf-8

Someone shared an Excel file with me (.xlsx, **not** .csv). Looking at the data in Excel it's obvious that the file is encoded using UTF-8, but Excel is interpreting the data as Windows 1252 encoded text. For example, where I expected to see 'ã' Excel displays 'Ã£' instead. 'ã' is `U+00E3` which is `0xC3 0xA3` encoded as UTF-8, which corresponds to 'Ã£' in Windows 1252.

How can I reload the file, without changing it, and have Excel interpret the data as UTF-8 encoded text?